# Excel Chart, Select Data Source, Select All Horizontal Axis Labels

Tags: excel

I've never see or used this feature before:
[image]

I've inherited some charts with the X values restricted in this dialog box. How do I remove these restrictions to display all X values (note, there does not seem to be a Select All option, and there are dozens of values to check, and more will be added in future - I don't want to have to update these every week)?  Basically, how to clear this setting and revert to a normal chart that displays all X values in the selected ranges?

Comment: Remake the chart?

Comment: yeah, @Selkie, I considered remaking the chart, but that seems kinda retrograde, I mean, would Microsoft really implement a process that couldn't be properly undone?